# Using SQLite's new WITH RECURSIVE CTE clause

Tags: sql, sqlite, common-table-expression

SQLite 3.8.3 added support for CTEs.  I tried some of the [sample CTEs on this page](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) and they work fine. However, after reading the documentation and trying to adapt some of the examples I am unable to create a simple test.

First, I create a simple table with two fields: `id` and `parent`.  This will create a simple tree or linked list of records:

```
CREATE TABLE test(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC,parent INTEGER);
```

Now I populate it with a few rows:

```
INSERT INTO test (parent) VALUES (NULL); 
INSERT INTO test (parent) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO test (parent) VALUES (2); 
INSERT INTO test (parent) VALUES (3);
```

After which I have a table that looks like this:

```
---+-------
id | parent
---+-------
 1 | NULL
 2 |  1
 3 |  2
 4 |  3
```

Now I want to generate a list of rows along the path between 3 and 1:

```
WITH RECURSIVE test1(id,parent) AS (
    VALUES(3,2) 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM test WHERE test.parent=test1.id) 
SELECT * FROM test1;
```

But I get the error:

```
no such column: test1.id
```

Both `test` and `test1` have an `id` field, so why does it claim it does not exist?  I have reviewed the documentation several times and don't see my mistake.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is necessary to include the `test1` table in the `SELECT`:

```
WITH RECURSIVE test1(id,parent) AS (
    VALUES(3,2)
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT test.id,test.parent FROM test,test1 WHERE test1.parent=test.id)
SELECT * FROM test1;
```

Note that the `WHERE` clause has been reversed, the original test in the question returns from the current row to the end, rather than from the end back to the start.